# need help for calling function

Tags: python

```
List_of_subject = ['add user', 'modify user', delete user'] and so on
```

I have a variable called subject. so depending upon the subject other function are called.
like add_user, modify_user, delete_user and so on.

So when my subject is 'add_user'
I want to call add_user function. I can call it like a normal function call.
But my list_of_subject is keep growing.

Can I DO :

```
List_of_subject.index(subject)
```

I get the index. So I want something like when index is 1 call add_user function.
Basically I want to link my function to list_of_subject list.
or it is ok to do this:`

```
if subject in list_of_subject:
  if subject == 'add user' :
        user = add_user()
  else if subject == ' modify user' 
        user = modify_user()
```

thanks.

thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Python, functions are [first-class objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_object), so you can put them into a dictionary:

```
fn = {'add user': add_user, 'modify user': modify_user}
```

To then call the relevant function, use:

```
user = fn[subject]()
```

Comment: Is thr any way I can store a return value.

Answer (score 0):

A (relatively) unsafe way of doing it would be

```
def add_user():
    (...)

list_of_subject = ['add_user', 'modify_user', 'delete_user']

if subject in list_of_subject:
    exec(subject + "()")
```